# clean ruby file before writing new content to it

Tags: ruby

Can somebody please guide me a way to **clean all existing content in a file before**  **writing new info to it in Ruby**? I'm writing the contents of this file with the code below:

```
logfile = File.new(filepath, "w")
logfile.write("my content")
```

However, I want all existing content in this "logfile" to be deleted before I write new info to it. How can I do this?

Comment: "w" should work. As documented in the [IO object](http://ruby-docs.com/docs/ruby_1.9.3/classes/IO.html), "w" means "Write-only, truncates existing file to zero length or creates a new file for writing." Can you make sure what you want isn't already happening or clarify your question with why you think the existing content in the file isn't being deleted?

Comment: Here's a gist where I used irb to show that "w" deletes all the previous text in the file: https://gist.github.com/4411135

Answer (score 12, accepted):

When opening a file for writing, i.e. using the "w" option, all previous contents of the file will be removed so you don't have to do anything explicitly to achieve that effect.